# How to darken page when video plays?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-video

I've seen this done a few times where the entire page will go dark or black while the video is playing. I'm wondering how this can be done using HTML CSS or Javascript.

Here's an example of what I mean: http://allmyvideos.net/vc0uqldjebnz

Comment: Digital downloads are also available

Comment: @gdoron I dunno if parcels get delivered to the batcave

Comment: Batman likes everything in dark...

Comment: @Najzero, When the `Wayne Enterprise` order parcels, they come.

Comment: robin delivers on saturdays, but he couldn't save usps

Comment: When you all wake up in Arkham Asylum tomorrow, you'll know why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an overlay div that takes up the whole screen and is dark or black. Set it to start as display none. Ensure that your video has a higher z-index. Then when the video is played, set the overlay div to display and it should make the page go dark.

For example, set a div like this:

```
<div id="overlay" style="display:none;position:fixed;width:100%;height:100%;top:0;left:0;opacity:0.6;">&nbsp;</div>
```

When the page loads, you won't see the overlay. Then when the video plays, set the display to anything but none which will show the overlay (example using jQuery)

```
$("#overlay").show();
```

Comment: .show is a jQuery method right? My prof wont let us use jQuery but I guess var overlay.style.display: block; should work just as fine right?

Comment: Yes, .show is jQuery. Your code of "var overlay.style..." won't work. In "regular" Javascript, do this: `document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "block"` That will do it.

Comment: Now I just need to find a way to find in and out but that's a lot easier to solve with quick searches